# How to connect html to native using phonegap in android

Tags: android, cordova

i started working on android using `phonegap`.  In **iphone** we use `phoneGap.exec(classname.methodname, arguments)` to connect to the native application from html. But how can you do it in Android? Can anyone help me in this please?

Thanks in advance,

Bharath gangupalli

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're trying to connect to a native plugin. The technique is generally the same on Android, include the native code and then call out using the Phonegap.Exec() wrapper. If you're looking for a sample to start from try out the BarcodeScanner plugin, which includes native code and the JS wrapper to call out to it:

https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner