# How to refer java class in phonegap html file

Tags: android, cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to connect html to native using phonegap in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883373/how-to-connect-html-to-native-using-phonegap-in-android)

How do I call a method that is in html file of www folder to src folder in phonegap.
I want to use Native methods in phonegap.Please help

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a 'phonegap plugin' for this purpose. Here's a good tutorial on this:

https://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-android.html